# Is it possible to extract metadata such as Content Created date from files - I can't get this with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, metadata

I need to extract the "Content Created" date out of thousands of files, but haven't been able to find a way to do this using PowerShell / other Command Line utility.

Does someone out there know a way to obtain this metadata? If so, please can you advise me. Thanks.

I've looked at various resources online, including this site, but haven't been successful thus far.

Here's a screenshot explaining what I'm trying to do.

[image: Extract Content Created Date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been unable to find a native powershell cmdlet which does what you want. However, I found this article: [Use PowerShell to Find Metadata from Photograph Files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/) and the script it used: [get file meta data function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804).

The article talks about image files, but the function is not specific for image files.

I tested it out on a folder containing a Word and an Excel file and the returned Metadata from the Word file contains the Content Created date. The Excel file does not contain/return that value. This is not unexpected as the Details tab of properties for the Excel file does not contain a Content Created value so it seems to be specific for Word files, and maybe some other file or document types.

**Update:**

You write that you need to extract this info from thousands of files, but if those files are anything but Word-files you probably won't be able to do that.

[image: Script with output from Word and Excel]

As far as I can tell this should work with the file types exposing the type of metadata you want. However, it seems that the *ContentCreated* property is unique to Word. I tried adding a text file (.txt), Acrobat PDF (.pdf), MS Access (.mdb), Excel (.xlxs) and a Word doc (.docx) file to my test folder and the only one that has/returns that metadata property is the Word file.

You should also be aware that the script seems to return metadata localized, so for me to programatically get the info i wanted I had to pipe the output of the script to `Select-Object -Property Name,'Innehåll skapat'` (which is the Swedish name for Content created). So if you're running on a non-english system you may need to check what the output looks like before creating your `Select-Object` statement.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I tried that suggestion before I asked the question here, but it doesn't produce the results I need.There's got to be some way to obtain that metatdata from the file's properties somehow. Hopefully somebody will be able to suggest a way forward. Thansk for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Hey, updated my answer with some more info. Basically it works for me, but only with Word-documents and I need to consider localization to retrieve the right information.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did some sampling myself and using this script, I can get **most** of my files' Content Created Dates - the remaining ~8% or so, I'll just have to try and find a different way to obtain the dates. Your help is greatly appreciated buddy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery in Excel 2013 or later (data tab). Connect to data> Folder.